# ffmpeg - extract 24-bit stereo wav to l/r mono wavs while preserving 24-bit?

Tags: ffmpeg

I used the following to extract mono l and r wavs from a 24-bit stereo wav file but the result is two 16-bit files:

`ffmpeg -i stereo24bit.wav -map_channel 0.0.0 left.wav -map_channel 0.0.1 right.wav`

What do I add to this or how do I change it to preserve the 24-bit depth of the original? Searching has not turned up an answer to this, some similar results but not what I am looking for.

Comment: Does adding in a `-c:a copy` fix it?

Comment: i tried it before the -map option and got a new stereo file on output rather than mono. thanks, though.

Comment: adding "-c:a pcm_s24le" before each instance of "-map_channels" produces 24bit mono files. is that the right way to do this? i want to be copying and to avoid any re-encoding. thanks, babag

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/686050/19943) seems to suggest that your command *should* work. At the very least it also provides another couple of options and is a potential duplicate candidate for this question. The main reason not to close as a dupe as it seems that the problem here is a specific case where ffmpeg appears to add an unnecessary conversion stage to the output.

Comment: thanks for this, Mokubai. that documentation is a little different than what i've found in the ffmpeg wiki pages. what i found there did not preserve the bit depth. i will try this method (channelsplit) which, to me at least, would imply that it might preserve the 24 bit depth. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to be copying and to avoid any re-encoding

`-map_channel` is an alias for the [pan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) filter. You can't filter a stream and also [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) it. However, since your input and output are PCM it doesn't really matter.

> How do I preserve the 24-bit depth of the original?

Some encoders, such as flac, support multiple sample formats, and `ffmpeg` will automatically attempt to choose the highest depth. But the default encoder for `.wav` output is pcm_s16le, which is only 16-bit (refer to `ffmpeg -h encoder=pcm_s16le`), so in this case you need to manually provide the name of an encoder that supports 24-bit, such as pcm_s24le.

## -map_channel

```
ffmpeg -i stereo24bit.wav -map_channel 0.0.0 -c:a pcm_s24le left.wav -map_channel 0.0.1 -c:a pcm_s24le right.wav
```

## channelsplit

Or if you want to use the [channelsplit](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelsplit) filter which might be more intuitive than the legacy `-map_channel` option:

```
ffmpeg -i stereo24bit.wav -filter_complex "channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FL|FR[left][right]" -map "[left]" -c:a pcm_s24le left.wav -map "[right]" -c:a pcm_s24le right.wav
```

Or in your particular case you can just use the channelsplit default values:

```
ffmpeg -i stereo24bit.wav -filter_complex "channelsplit[left][right]" -map "[left]" -c:a pcm_s24le left.wav -map "[right]" -c:a pcm_s24le right.wav
```

## Verifying

You can add the `-loglevel debug` global option to view more details about the process:

```
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55be6dfc6e00] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 's32
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0x55be6dfcab40] picking s32p out of 6 ref:s32
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0x55be6dfcab40] [SWR @ 0x55be6dfcb000] Using s32p internally between filters
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0x55be6dfcab40] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s32 r:44100Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s32p r:44100Hz
[auto_resampler_1 @ 0x55be6dfe0940] ch:1 chl:1 channels (FR) fmt:s32p r:44100Hz -> ch:1 chl:1 channels (FR) fmt:s32 r:44100Hz
```